# Angularjs and select with array including __proto__

Tags: javascript, select, angularjs

I have an angular program that creates a select with options. I use an array that contains two objects.

I have created a jsFiddle example here: http://jsfiddle.net/ucHAe/

However the select ends up creating an extra select option. I am confounded by this extra option and can only think this is due to the existence of third and final entry called '**proto**'. I am using chrome v28.0.1500.95.

Console output for chrome console.log:

```
[Object, Object]
0: Object
    id: 0
    mode: "Search"
    url: "http://google.com"
    __proto__: Object
1: Object
    id: 1
    mode: "Social"
    url: "http://facebook.com"
    __proto__: Object
length: 2
__proto__: Array[0]
```

Any idea's why this is happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The so-called extra select option (which I assume is the blank option) is created since you set the `ng-model` incorrectly. According to the comprehension expression defined in the `ng-options`, you need to set `selectOption` to the object rather than an ID.

Add this at the end of the controller will fix it, so there will be only 2 shown in the drop down list.

```
$scope.selectOption =  $scope.options[0];
```

Hope it helps.

<kbd>**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/V9Ex6/)**</kbd>

Comment: That definitely solved my problem I didn't think of it in terms of objects, which makes loads of sense. The selected option would then assign the appropriate reference. Good to know for the future.